# Как отправить кросс-доменный запрос к steam через XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, steam-web-api, cross-domain

Никак не могу получить данные, хочу запарсить инвентарь юзера, раньше делал через php, но steam из-за частых обращений с ip сервера ставит временный бан, решил перенести парсинг на сторону клиента.

`Пробовал как через Ajax, так и через XMLHttpRequest`

Вот такой код использую:

Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/"+steamid+"/inventory/json/730/2",
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function( data ) {
           console.log(  data  );
        },
        error: function(e) {
           console.log('errorrrrrrrrrr', e.message);
        }
    });
```

Бьет такую ошибку: 
[image: Ошибки в консоли]

[image: Ошибка в json]

> Никак не могу понять в чем дело, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: > Пробовал как через Ajax, так и через XMLHttpRequest
Это то же самое ) А вообще браузер не даст такой запрос послать.

Comment: @jekaby, от заголовков зависит - может и дать.

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще то да) Только какой смысл для steam в Origin: пропускать всякие сомнительные хосты) И, возможно, запрос браузер послать то даст, а вот ответ обработан не будет.

Comment: @jekaby, не подскажешь тогда, как решить данную проблему с баном на стороне сервера ?

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан я нет.. может кто-то другой знает. Все заголовки ставить как в реальных запросах. А если там лимит запросов по ip, то только увеличением количества ip-адресов..

Comment: @jekaby, если это public api - то почему бы нет?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> dataType: 'jsonp',
> jsonp: false,
> ```

Весьма сомнительная комбинация.

Comment: ахаха, плюсанул))